# Currently my unicorn master needs to be killed manually before each deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, unicorn

I'm using capistrano in my rails4 app and everytime I'm release a new version (=> `cap production deploy`) I need to kill the unicorn master on the server so that the capistrano can walk without any failures.

```
### How can I automate the process of killing the unicorn process? 

This is how my deploy.rb is looking like:

lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'maalify'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:iNeedCode/Maalify.git'
set :deploy_to, '/opt/www/maalify'
set :user, 'root'
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets}


set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.1'
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_path, "~/.rbenv"
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w(rake gem bundle ruby rails)
set :rbenv_roles, :all
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml .rbenv-vars} # create these files manually ones on the server



# Capristrano3 unicorn
set :unicorn_pid, "/opt/www/maalify/current/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
set :unicorn_config_path, "/opt/www/maalify/current/config/unicorn.rb"

# Clean up all older releases
before :deploy, "unicorn:stop"
after "deploy:publishing", "unicorn:start"
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"


namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
    end
  end

end
```

## Update

Here is the Unicorn.rb

```
# set path to application
app_dir = "/opt/www/maalify"
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"
working_directory "#{app_dir}/current"

# Set unicorn options
worker_processes 1
preload_app true
timeout 30

# Set up socket location
listen "#{shared_dir}/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock", :backlog => 64

# Logging
stderr_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{shared_dir}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

# Set master PID location
pid "#{shared_dir}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
```

After adding the `before_fork` I'm still getting the same error as previously when I didn't kill unicorn by hand:

```
/opt/www/maalify/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:206:in `pid=': Already running on PID:16268 (or pid=/opt/www/maalify/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid is stale) (ArgumentError)
        from /opt/www/maalify/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:135:in `start'
        from /opt/www/maalify/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/www/maalify/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
        from /opt/www/maalify/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please, add unicorn config file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've noticed in your unicorn config file next directive:

```
preload_app true
```

Here is info from [docs](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html):

> HUP - reloads config file and gracefully restart all workers. If the
>   "preload_app" directive is false (the default), then workers will also
>   pick up any application code changes when restarted. If "preload_app"
>   is true, then application code changes will have no effect; USR2 +
>   QUIT (see below) must be used to load newer code in this case.

You can set directive `preload_app` to false and then if you need to reload code, send `HUP` signal to master process.

But here is another way to reload code without downtime. You need to implement `USR2 + QUIT` method in config. It means when you send `USR2` signal, unicorn starts new instance of application without killing old one. You can hook `before_fork` callback to which will kill old instance painless for you.

Here is example, add this to unicorn config:

```
before_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!

  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Now send USR2 signal to master process and check it out!

Next step is change your deploy.rb. You need to remove all `unicorn` hooks and add next one:

```
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
namespace :deploy do
  task :restart do
    invoke 'unicorn:legacy_restart'
  end
end
```

And last step: fix pid path in deploy.rb.

```
set :unicorn_pid, "/opt/www/maalify**/current/shared/**tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
```

Must be:

```
set :unicorn_pid, "/opt/www/maalify/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
```

Comment: I'm using `USR2` which I've defined in the `/etc/init.d/unicorn_maalify` file

Comment: @codeshifter then as you can see in doc, you need to implement before_fork in config for workers or to set `preload_app` directive to `false`. Give me a sec, I'll update answer.

Comment: have tried adding the before_block and also toggled the `preload_app` but its getting the same error.

Comment: @codeshifter weird. Did you killed unicorn by hand and then started it again before testing my answer?

Comment: Nope. didn't killed unicorn by hand. was thinking that this will resolve that :) Just let me check with killing ones by hand.

Comment: nope still getting the ` `pid=': Already running on PID:19191 ` error

Comment: Thanks. Now please show me where defined `unicorn:stop` and `unicorn:start` in your deployment configuration. Also I'd like to ask you for clarification to provide how you start\stop\restart your unicorn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100473/discussion-between-codeshifter-and-axvm).